# How to Hide the Native Mouseover a Title Element?

Tags: html, css

I have designed a table whereby I want to display tooltips when `hover` over an item.

This is what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/snSMC.png

However, the problem I am now having is that the title displays twice! Once using the style I created and once as the default browser behavior with the `<a title="">` element...

How can I solve this?

Edit: I have now attached an image, so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: I don't see where the title is displayed twice?

Comment: It's in the element "a", in the table design, on the left row. You can hover with your mouse over the element and a tooltip will display. TWICE. Once with the css that I made and once more with the default browser setting I believe...

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own and store the `title` attribute's data in there and then use the new attribute to display that data and yes remove the `title` attribute.

Ok so let's explain it, I see you have used the `title` property's text of those tabs hyperlinks to show that popup. I am suggesting you to make another property, it could be named anything like `data-popup`, then remove your `title` attribute and then change your script and make the use of the `data-popup` property.

*Sorry for ""attribute"" :P*.

Comment: But how then will I input the text into that property? If I want it to display on hover (mouseover), I can't think of another way than this one...

Comment: Use JavaScript's getAttribute() method on the DOM object, using "data-popup" as the argument.